# Is there any way to disable all thrown exceptions in iOS market release?

Tags: ios, xcode, exception, app-store, release

Working on an iOS app. Apart from deciding whether it is right action or not, is there any way to disable all exception (which are thrown) in iOS market release? So that it will act like, all exceptions will be received in a common block which will do nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply a 'catch-all' exception handler using [NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1409609-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler), which you call by passing a closure, e.g:

```swift
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
  print("Uncaught exception: \(exception)")
}
```

A decent place to put this code would be in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. That being said, it's probably a better idea to protect specific parts of the code which may fail with [try/catch](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html) blocks in which you can mitigate the problems and prevent the app from getting into undefined states.